# Scala, Quill: Как реализовать вложенный запрос через DSL

Tags: scala

Есть необходимость в запросе к PostgreSQL для получения записаей у которых последний статус равен одному из перечисленных.
Пробовал написать запрос через `infix` но при указании списка статусов приходит пустой ответ, хотя, если взять запрос из лога и вставить в консоль БД, приходит несколько записей.

Сам запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
SELECT t1.* from table t1
       where 
            t1.status in ('New','Done') and 
            t1.id = (select t2.id from table t2 where t2.name = t1.name order by t2.time desc limit 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Рабочий пример:](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8W3rDSkBS72x05NnszMsig)

```
case class JobStatus(
    name: String,
    status: String,
    time: Long,
    id: Long = -1
  )

val q = quote {
      query[JobStatus]
        .filter(s => liftQuery(statuses).contains(s.status))
        .filter(s => query[JobStatus].filter(_.name == s.name).sortBy(_.time)(Ord.desc).take(1).map(_.id).contains(s.id))
}
ctx.run(q)
```

После компиляции получается следующий SQL:

```
SELECT s.name, s.status, s.time, s.id FROM job_status s WHERE s.status IN (?, ?) AND s.id IN (SELECT x1.id FROM job_status x1 WHERE x1.name = s.name ORDER BY x1.time DESC LIMIT 1)
```